# How do I implement five star rating in Django DetailView?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-class-based-views

I'm currently working on a restaurant review site and I'm struggling with displaying a five star rating comment form in a class based DetailView page.

How do I implement a five star rating system for my class based RestarurantDetail page? I would like to change the appearence on my Integerfield "rate" to a five star rating field. I would still like to display all other fields in the comment form as normal, perhaps with crispy forms (but it's perhaps not possible if I want to customize the rate field?)

If you need aditional information, just let me know!

**Code**

Restaurant Model (parts of it) in Models.py

```
class Restaurant(models.Model): 
name        = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
country     = models.CharField(max_length = 75)
city        = models.CharField(max_length = 75)
address     = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
categori    = models.ManyToManyField(Kategori)
description = models.CharField(max_length = 300, blank=True)
approved    = models.BooleanField(default=False) 
geom        = PointField(null=True)
owner       = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


def __str__(self):
    return self.name

class Meta:
    unique_together = ('country', 'city', 'adress')
```

Comment Model in Models.py

```
class Comment(models.Model):

ALTERNATIVES_1 = (
    ('Alt 1', 'Alt 1'),
    ('Alt 2', 'Alt 2'),
    ('Alt 3', 'Alt 3'),
)

restaurant       = models.ForeignKey(Restaurant, on_delete = models.CASCADE, related_name='comments')
user             = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
title            = models.CharField(max_length = 50, blank = True)
comment          = models.TextField(max_length = 500, blank = True)
rate             = models.IntegerField(default=1)
approved_comment = models.BooleanField(default=False)
likes            = models.IntegerField(default=0)
status_1         = models.CharField(max_length = 100, choices=ALTERNATIVES_1, default='Alt 1')
time_of_visit    = models.DateField(default = datetime.date.today) 
created_at       = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
updated_at       = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

def __str__(self):
    return '{}-{}'.format(self.restaurant.name, str(self.user))

def approve(self):
    self.approved_comment = True
    self.save()
```

Comment form in forms.py

```
class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Comment
    fields = ('title', 'comment', 'rate', 'status_1', 'time_of_visit')
    widgets = {
        'time_of_visit': DatePickerInput(),
        'rate': forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control'})
    }
```

Restaurant detail view in views.py (my main issue)

```
class RestaurantDetailView(DetailView):
model = Restaurant
template_name = 'core/restaurant_detail.html'

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(RestaurantDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    #context['comments'] = self.object.comments.filter(approved_comment=True)
    context['form'] = CommentForm()
    return context

def point_dataset(self, request):
    points = serialize('geojson', Restaurant.objects.all())
    return HttpResponse(points, content_type='json')

def get_queryset(self):
    return Restaurant.objects.annotate(avg_rating=Avg('comments__rate'))
```

Comment: If it's about backend, you can add five additional integer fields to count stars (star_1, start_2, etc.) instead of the rate field or just create a new model Rate with one integer field stars and foreign key to Restaurant model. 
If it's about frontend, add five stars manually. Each star is a button that sends a corresponding rating.

Comment: Thanks Crosby! I I try the approach with a new rate model with foreign key to the Restaurant model this would solve all issues with the front end. I would also need a Foreign key to the comment model if I would like to display each rating along with its comment?

Comment: Yes, if you are going to separate Comment and Rate into two different models.